# express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body)

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

file name script.js.

While running my CRUD application I'm getting this error.
Getting error at this specific line of code can anyone suggest some solution please?

Let me know if you wanna have a complete look at the code I will post it in comment

**error**

```
"express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead script.js:18:5
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: <h2 style="font-family: Malgun Gothic; color: midnightblue ">Welcome to Edureka Node.js MongoDB Tutorial!!</h2>
```

**code**

```
//Create a welcome message and direct them to the main page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send(
     
'<h2 style="font-family: Malgun Gothic; color: midnightblue ">Welcome to Edureka Node.js MongoDB 
 Tutorial!!</h2>'
 ,'Click Here to go to <b> <a href="/course">Course Page</a> </b>');
});
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change like this it's work

```
res.status(200).send(     
  '<h2 style="font-family: Malgun Gothic; color: midnightblue ">Welcome to Edureka 
     Node.js MongoDB Tutorial!!</h2>'
     ,'Click Here to go to <b> <a href="/course">Course Page</a> </b>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked for me . also just edited this line for minor error fix  ,'Node.js MongoDB Tutorial!!</h2>'